# WebControl Event does not update Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have created a webcontrol with some events. It is located in an UpdatePanel. 
When I click on a button on my webcontrol, it fires its event which updates a label. I added a breakpoint and the label should be updated. However, the label is not updating on my page. Here's my code for you:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderAdmin" Runat="Server">

    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ProductWebControl1" EventName="OnOrderSmall" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h1>Choose Your Food</h1>
            <uc1:ProductWebControl ID="ProductWebControl1" OnOnOrderSmall="ProductWebControl1_OnOrderSmall" runat="server" />
            Date: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelTest">abc</asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

My Codebehind looks like the following:

```
protected void ProductWebControl1_OnOrderSmall(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

I tried the different update modes of the UpdatePanel to no avail. I'm a bit lost right now, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this and bless you all.

Comment: Looks fine to me apart from the fact that you use `OrderSmall` as `EventName` and `OnOnOrderSmall` for the event. Since you have edited that, is it a typo? Have you also tried `ChildrenAsTriggers=false`?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for commenting. I figured the OnOn problem, it was indeed a problem there (the event name should be OnOrderSmall and trigger OrderSmall). I'm changing this again in the code above.

As a small note, instead of getting the label to change text I got the control to have itself disappear but then it wouldn't appear when I'd click another button.

Could this all be because of some Javascript problem? Note that the label still isn't showing any sign of life.

Comment: Can you try - setting the UpdateMode to "Always" and ChildrenAsTriggers="true" on the UpdatePanel, and remove the Triggers section. Does it work now ?

Comment: sh1rts and Tim!
I changed the UpdateMode to Always and ChildrenAsTriggers=true and it started working now! Label is showing text!!! Thanks sh1rts!